# Getting error code in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I'm trying to run OLSR protocol using OMNET++ 4.6.. it's working fine but before end the simulation I get this error

```
Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073741819
Working directory: D:/old/VANETProject-master/VANETProject-master/VANETSim/simulations/olsr
Command line: ../../src/inet/inet.exe -r 0 -n ../../src;.. omnetpp.ini

Environment variables:
OMNETPP_ROOT=D:/omnetpp-4.6-src-windows/omnetpp-4.6/
PATH=;D:\omnetpp-4.6-src-windows\omnetpp-4.6\bin;D:\omnetpp-4.6-src-windows\omnetpp-4.6\tools\win32\usr\bin;D:\omnetpp-4.6-src-windows\omnetpp-4.6\tools\win32\mingw32\bin;D:/omnetpp-4.6-src-windows/omnetpp-4.6/ide/jre/bin/client;D:/omnetpp-4.6-src-windows/omnetpp-4.6/ide/jre/bin;D:/omnetpp-4.6-src-windows/omnetpp-4.6/ide/jre/lib/i386;.;D:\omnetpp-4.6-src-windows\omnetpp-4.6\bin;D:\omnetpp-4.6-src-windows\omnetpp-4.6\tools\win32\mingw32\bin;D:\omnetpp-4.6-src-windows\omnetpp-4.6\tools\win32\usr\local\bin;D:\omnetpp-4.6-src-windows\omnetpp-4.6\tools\win32\usr\bin;D:\omnetpp-4.6-src-windows\omnetpp-4.6\tools\win32\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python27;D:\sumo-winbin-0.19.0\sumo-0.19.0\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;D:\sumo-025\bin;D:\sumo-025\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;D:\omnetpp-4.6-src-windows\omnetpp-4.6\tools\win32\usr\bin\site_perl;D:\omnetpp-4.6-src-windows\omnetpp-4.6\tools\win32\usr\bin\vendor_perl;D:\omnetpp-4.6-src-windows\omnetpp-4.6\tools\win32\usr\bin\core_perl;D:\omnetpp-4.6-src-windows\omnetpp-4.6;
OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=D:\omnetpp-4.6-src-windows\omnetpp-4.6\images
```

So any one can advice me to fix this error?

Comment: Which version of INET do you use? Could you show your NED files as well as omnetpp.ini file?

Comment: Hi , I'm using INETMANET .. my problem i have two map .. one of them working fine without any problem and the another get this error above . so any advice ,, Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide more detail about these map? Could you show your NED files as well as omnetpp.ini file? Did you add any own code to this model?

Comment: nope .. i just add map .. i already have another map and it's working fine. but in my map not ... although this map that not work here it working fine with AODV protocol ..   Plz can you send me your email in my email so i can send to you the ini fie and the ned file on ur email .. my email ( tariqemad@gmail.com ) .. Thanks in advance

Comment: StackOverflow is a place where someone **publicly** asks a question and others **publicly** try to answer them.

Comment: yes sure, but how i can send the ini file and the ned file via comment ? Is there any way ... Thanks

Comment: You can edit your question and paste the content of your files.